# How to handle changes of submodels in main model (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

What is the best practice to update dynamically created checkboxes states from model? Acutal values for checkboxes are held in submodels of main model and being changed accordingly to it's logic. Checkboxes' properties bind to their individual FooViewModels. But how to change FooViewModel's properties then?

1 way: main model fires especial event -> main VM handles it and finds target FooViewModel to update using event args -> main VM sets target FooViewModel properties with values specified in event args -> checkbox is updated via bindings to FooViewModel

2 way: Main model holds observable collection of FooModels implementing INPC and each is being wrapped with FooViewModel (using CollectionChanged event in main VM). Main model set some FooModel's property -> FooViewModel handles PropertyChanged and transfers it further firing own PropertyChanged event -> checkbox is updated via bindings to FooViewModel.
Transferrence code in FooViewModel:

```
this._model.PropertyChanged += (s, a) => this.RaisePropertyChangedEvent(a.PropertyName);
```

My implementation of 2nd way is next:

```
// MainModel class that holds collection of extra models (CfgActionModel):
class MainModel: BindableBase
{
    ObservableCollection<CfgActionModel> _actionsColl
        = new ObservableCollection<CfgActionModel>();

    public ObservableCollection<CfgActionModel> ActionCollection
    {
        get => this._actionsColl;
    }

    public void AddAction(ConfigEntry cfgEntry, bool isMeta)
    {
        CfgActionModel actionModel = new CfgActionModel()
        {
            CfgEntry = cfgEntry,
            Content = cfgEntry.ToString(),
            IsEnabled = true,
            IsChecked = false
        };

        this._actionsColl.Add(actionModel);
    }
}

// Extra model that is wrapped with CfgActionViewModel:
class CfgActionModel: BindableBase
{
    ConfigEntry _cfgEntry; // Custom enumeration value unique for each checkbox
    string _content;
    bool _isEnabled = false;
    bool _isChecked = false;

    public ConfigEntry CfgEntry
    {
        get => this._cfgEntry;
        set
        {
            if (this._cfgEntry == value) return;

            this._cfgEntry = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(CfgEntry));
        }
    }

    public string Content
    {
        get => this._content;
        set
        {
            if (this._content == value) return;

            this._content = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(Content));
        }
    }

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get => this._isEnabled;
        set
        {
            if (this._isEnabled == value) return;

            this._isEnabled = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(IsEnabled));
        }
    }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => this._isChecked;
        set
        {
            if (this._isChecked == value) return;

            this._isChecked = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(IsChecked));
        }
    }
}

// CfgActionViewModel that is checkbox in UI is bound to:
class CfgActionViewModel: BindableBase
{
    CfgActionModel _model;

    public CfgActionViewModel(CfgActionModel model)
    {
        this._model = model;

        this._model.PropertyChanged += (s, a) => this.RaisePropertyChangedEvent(a.PropertyName);
    }

    public string Content
    {
        get => this._model.Content;
        set => this._model.Content = value;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get => this._model.IsEnabled;
        set => this._model.IsEnabled = value;
    }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => this._model.IsChecked;
        set => this._model.IsChecked = value;
    }
}

// MainViewModel where we fill the model with data:
class MainViewModel
{
    MainModel model;

    readonly ObservableCollection<CfgActionViewModel> _actionVMColl = new ObservableCollection<CfgActionViewModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<CfgActionViewModel> ActionVMCollection => this._actionVMColl;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.model = new MainModel();

        this.model.ActionCollection.CollectionChanged += (s, a) =>
        {
            // when new model is created we create new ViewModel wrapping it
            if (a.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                CfgActionModel newModel = (CfgActionModel) a.NewItems[0];
                CfgActionViewModel actionViewModel = new CfgActionViewModel(newModel);

                _actionVMColl.Add(actionViewModel);
            }
        };

        model.AddAction(ConfigEntry.AutoBuy, false);
        model.AddAction(ConfigEntry.Bomb, false);
    }
}
```

DataTemplate in View looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mvvm:CfgActionViewModel}">
    <CheckBox
        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" 
        Content="{Binding Path=Content, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Is it acceptable by MVVM to avoid interaction with MainViewModel somewhere (2nd way) or each subViewModel's property must be set by MainViewModel (1st way)?

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are acceptable. But personally, I would do approach #1 to keep my Models as thin as possible.

You can refer to the sample code on how you can do approach #1.

```
public class MainViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<SubViewModel> SubViewModels { get; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SubViewModels = new ObservableCollection<SubViewModel>();

        SubViewModels.CollectionChanged += SubViewModels_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void SubViewModels_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach(var subVM in e.NewItems.Cast<SubViewModel>())
            {
                subVM.PropertyChanged += SubViewModel_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }

        // TODO: Unsubscribe to SubViewModels that are removed in collection to avoid memory leak.
    }

    private void SubViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case nameof(SubViewModel.IsChecked):
                // TODO: Do your thing here...
                break;
        }
    }
}

public class SubViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private bool _isChecked;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => _isChecked;
        set => SetProperty(ref _isChecked, value);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I don't even need to include any Models in the sample code which means that all the logic here are all clearly part of the presentation layer.
Now, you can focus on your business/domain logic in your Models.

Comment: So my todolist is:
1. If user changes checkbox state I have to notify main model using some method (because ViewModel must not update model's collection directly not respecting her logic) in body of SubViewModel_PropertyChanged 
2. If main model sets some SubModel's property it fires an event
But how to fill the MainViewModel with SubViewModels? Should I handle CollectionChanged of main model's collection or may be it's better to create specialized event?

Comment: Try the suggested approach first then I believe your additional questions will be answered.